# function is continuous iff its composition with a curve is continuous

Tags: calculus, metric-spaces, continuity, curves

Please help me answer the following question:

$ f: R^n \to R \space is \space continuous \space \iff \space \forall \space \gamma: [a,b] \to R^n \space . \space f \circ \gamma : [a,b] \to R \space is \space continuous$

I succeeded to prove the first direction(given f is continuous). This seems to be the "easy" direction. As for the other direction, I thought about the following solution but I'm not quite sure it is correct:

let $ \epsilon $ be a positive number.
We know that $f\circ \gamma $ is continuous, thus if $\forall t_1 \in [a,b] \space. \exists \delta>0 .\forall t_2 \in [a,b] . |\gamma(t_1)-\gamma(t_2)|
<\delta => \space |f(\gamma(t_1)) - f(\gamma(t_2))|<\epsilon$

In addition , w also know that $\gamma$ is a curve and therefore a continuous function:
$ \forall t_1 \in [a,b] \space. \exists \delta _1 >0 .\forall t_2 \in [a,b] . |t_1-t_2|
<\delta_1 => \space |\gamma(t_1) - \gamma(t_2)|<\delta$

now, for conclusion : 
$ \forall t_1 \in [a,b] \space. \exists \delta _1 >0 .\forall t_2 \in [a,b] . |t_1-t_2|
<\delta_1 => \space |\gamma(t_1) - \gamma(t_2)|<\delta =>|f(\gamma(t_1)) - f(\gamma(t_2))|<\epsilon $

and this is correct for every $t_1,t_2 \in R $ and for every $\gamma(t_1),\gamma(t_2) \in R^n$ and therefore f is continuous. $\blacksquare$

I'm quite sure it is not enough , so please help me solve it correctly or tell me if this is a good solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proposal fails because once a choice of $\gamma$ is made, too many points are missing. Let's try by way of contradiction. Suppose $f$ is not continuous at $x_0$. This means there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that for every $k\ge1$ there is a point $x_k$ such that $\|x_k-x_0\|<1/k$ but $\|f(x_k)-f(x_0)\|>\varepsilon$. What we need is a curve $\gamma$ from $x_1$ to $x_0$ *passing through all* $x_k$. This can be produced glueing linear interpolations $\gamma_k:[1-1/k,1-1/(k+1)]\to[x_k,x_{k+1}]$. All together define a continuous function $\gamma:[0,1)\to{\mathbb R}^n$ that extends continuously by $\gamma(1)=x_0$ by construction. Also by construction $f\circ\gamma$ is not continuous at $1$.

Answer (score 0):

The proposition in your question is correct even if we restrict $\gamma$ to the $C^1$ curves. You can see theorem 12 in the paper [A Continuous Tale](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/real-analysis-exchange/volume-41/issue-1/A-Continuous-Tale/rae/1490752816.full) for details, it is open access.