If $f$ is discontinuous but continuous for each component,is there a continuous function $g$ that makes $f \circ g$ discontinuous for some component?
For example
$$f(x,y)= \begin{cases} \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2} & (x,y)\neq (0,0)\\ 0 &(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$
$f$ is discontinuous but continuous for each component, In polar coordinates(Equivalent to compounding with a continuous function)
$$f(r,\vartheta)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\vartheta) & r \neq 0 \\ 0 & r=0 \end{cases}$$
Obviously, $f$ is discontinuous to $r$
So I want to know if $f$ is discontinuous but continuous for each component,is there a continuous function $g$ that makes $f \circ g$ discontinuous for some component?

I guess you mean the word "component"   to refer to the variables, either $x,y$   or later $r, \theta$

This seems to say the answer is "yes": https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099043/function-is-continuous-iff-its-composition-with-a-curve-is-continuous
